# A Commercial MP3 Encoder/Decoder to use with Sox/Audacity

Tags: linux, command-line, mp3, lame, sox

In recent days i've been looking into a way to mix together MP3 files at the point of upload to a website, which is hosted on a linux machine.

So far, thanks to the community, i've learned that using SoX over the command line is probably the most efficient way to actually produce a mixed file from two sources.  I have also discovered that Audacity may also be useable for the purpose.

Unfortunately, both of these programs being free - they do not support the MP3 format due to legal issues around patents and licensing.  I know that support can be added with LAME, however this still remains illegal because LAME is also free and is not licensed by the patent owners.

So I'm looking for a way to add MP3 encoder/decoder support to Sox, Audacity or a similar command-line enabled program, so that it can be used legally within a commercial website.  Searches have once again come up blank, does anyone know of a solution please?

Comment: Why use `mp3` format at all? it it one of the worst lossy codecs nowadays. Consider using `Ogg/Vorbis` or `Opus`, they are totally free and pretty effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the LAME plugin, but purchase a patent license covering your use of the patented technology.  [mp3licensing.com](http://mp3licensing.com/) has further information, including the royalty rates.

It [appears](https://madfileformatscience.garymcgath.com/2016/04/05/mp3patent/) that the last of the known MP3 patents will expire in the US on December 30, 2017.

Comment: Sounds simple when you put it like that!  I think the client is going to adopt a different approach and get the contributors to mix/clip their own tracks now, which suits me just fine!

Comment: www.mp3licensing.com looks like some beginner did it on a sunday evening. Links are broken, the site's page structure has flaws, and some links do not lead where they should. Moreover, there are other parts of the website which are not user friendly and totally uncommon (e.g. whole page's text in an image). I have strong doubt's that this is a website which is run by a global player in entertainment systems.

Comment: [Fraunhofer's site](http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/ff/amm/lizenz/mp3.html) confirms that Technicolor and www.mp3licensing.com is their *"software and patent licensing partner for mp3*".